# Chain rule for $\sigma$-finite measure.

Tags: measure-theory, chain-rule

Let $\mu,\nu,\omega$ $\sigma$-finite measures over the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ such that
$\mu\ll\nu\ll\omega$.

I am asked to show that $\mu\ll\omega$ and that
\begin{align*}
   \frac{d\mu}{d\omega}
   = \frac{d\nu}{d\omega} \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}.
\end{align*}

So I know that I'm supposed to show that these two functions are equal but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: How about writing what are the RN derivatives?

Answer (score 3):

$\int_E f \frac {d\nu} {d\omega} \, d\omega =\int_E f \, d\nu$ for any non-negative measurable function $f$. To see this note that this holds when $f=I_A$ by definition; now extend to simple functions and use Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that it holds whenever $f$ is a  non-negative measurable function. Now put $f= \frac {d\mu} {d\nu}$. You get $\int_E \frac {d\mu} {d\nu} \frac {d\nu} {d\omega} \, d\omega =\int_E \frac {d\mu} {d\nu} \, d\nu=\mu (E)$. By definition of Radon Nikodym derivative this implies $\frac {d\mu} {d\nu} \frac {d\nu} {d\omega}=\frac {d\mu} {d\omega}$